# Check number of words in a file that contain a specific letter

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

Bash command to check number of words in a file that contain letter “a”

Comment: [I will not post homework questions on Unix&Linux](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-MeO65BoP3VU/VLb1Q8JGBPI/AAAAAAAAGxg/48tIxC7Yjrg/w426-h237/Homework.gif)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suppose that we have this test file:

```
$ cat file
the cat in the hat
the quick brown dog
jack splat
```

With `grep` implementations that have adopted GNU's `-o` extension, we can retrieve all the words containing `a`:

```
$ grep -wo '[[:alnum:]]*a[[:alnum:]]*' file
cat
hat
jack
splat
```

We can count those words:

```
$ grep -wo '[[:alnum:]]*a[[:alnum:]]*' file | wc -l
4
```

Comment: Personally I would consider using `grep -c` and would also use [aA] or the -i flag to ensure that words with an upper case A are also counted.

Comment: Adding `-i` for case-insensitivity is a good idea.   `-c` counts the number of matching lines of _input_, not matching words in the _output_.   For example, with the input file above, `grep -woc '[[:alnum:]]*a[[:alnum:]]*' file` returns `2` because there are two matching lines.  By contrast,  `grep -wo '[[:alnum:]]*a[[:alnum:]]*' file | grep -c .` would give the correct answer.   Alternatively, @yaegashi's approach shows a good use of `grep -c`.

Answer (score 7):

POSIXly:

```
<file tr -s '[:space:]' '[\n*]' | grep -c a
```

Here, *words* are sequences of non-spacing characters.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a Perl way:

```
 perl -0lnE 'say scalar grep(/a/,split(/\s/,$_));' file
```

And an `awk` way:

```
 awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($(i)~/a/){k++}}}END{print k}' file
```

Comment: Won't that just give you the number of a's in the file rather than the number of words containing a?

Comment: @Colin'tHart um. Yes. Indeed it will. Thanks, no idea what I was thinking there.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="[[:space:][:punct:]]"; c=0}
     index($0,"a"){c++} 
     END{print c}'
```

Using a version of `awk` that supports multi-character **R**ecord **S**eparator (`RS`), eg. GNU awk, you can cause `awk` to read one word per record.

Within that record, the *`index(in, string)`* function searches *`in`* for the first occurrence of *`string`*, and returns the *1-based* character position of where it is found. If not found, `index()` returns *0*. Thus the return value can be treated as a boolean condition test (0 = false, not zero = true). Note, this is not a regular expression search.

If a match is found, the variable `c` is incremented by 1 (`c++`)

The `c=0` is required in the `BEGIN{}` block, for when `c` is never incremented - which would cause `c` to be `null` instead of `0`. Another way to handle this issue would be to `print 0+c` (in the `END{}` block)

Comment: This relies on a version of awk that supports multi-character `RS` (e.g. GNU awk). I would probably put a `+` at the end of the pattern `[[:space:][:punct:]]+` to match one or more characters and just use `/a/{c++}` (although I guess `index` might be marginally quicker). Some explanation would make your answer more useful.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep:

```
 grep -oP '\b\w*a+\w*\b' file
```